# SharePoint 2019 and VS2019 Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': A timeout has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, solution-deployment, visual-studio-2019

We are having SharePoint 2019 farm and we used to deploy our custom changes like lists, pagelayouts and content types through SharePoint farm solutions. Whenever we deploy the changes to the SharePoint we are getting the below error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': A timeout has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process

Steps tried to fix this issue:

1. Added the signed in Visual studio account to site collection administrator
2. Tried to add registry keys which are meant for VS 2013 and VS 2017
3. Added the appropriate permissions to virtual directories and 16 hive folders.

Nothing worked out for us and we are really stuck on this issue. Can anyone please advice on this.